# I want to trim the string obtained via RichInputText. How can that be done in the bean?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a RichInputText component in my JSF page, which has a binding to an attribute in an associated java bean.
I want the leading and trailing spaces to be removed from this string, before saving it to database. How can this be done via managed bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> myIt.setValue(myIt.getValue().trim())

if you want to replace the string in the RIT component.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the **trim** method in java :

for example you have RichInputText called **myIt**. and you have generated the  accessories for **myIt**  (setters and getters) in your bean

Before saving :

```
String trimmedValue="";
String inputTextValue="";
inputTextValue= this.getMyIt().getValue();

trimmedValue=inputTextValue.trim();
```

Comment: why not String trimmedValue = myIt.getValue.trim();  ?  Why  extra, intermediate var?

Comment: What standards?

Comment: Does simple myIt.setValue( trimmedValue ) work for getting this trimmed value saved in the component?